# tkinter Listbox loses its selection when clicking elsewhere on the form

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

When a tkinter form includes a listbox and other widgets, clicking on the other widgets  (especially if the mouse is dragged) causes the listbox to lose its selection -- meaning that the element(s) that was/were selected/highlighted in the lisbox become unselected.

I've seen this problem discussed in one or two places on the Net, with this solution proposed: set the listbox `exportselection` value to `False`:

```
lb = Listbox(leftPane, width=24, height=4, selectmode=EXTENDED)
lb.exportselection = False
```

But that doesn't work at all in my apps. (Tried on Tkinter 8.5 and Tkinter 8.6.1, Python 3.3, Python 3.4... on a variety of Linux distributions. The problem is remarkably constant, regardless of the app in which the listobox is, or the environment in which it's deployed.)

Ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep selections highlighted in a tkinter Listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048609/how-to-keep-selections-highlighted-in-a-tkinter-listbox)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You need to use the [config](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.config-method) (or configure) method:

```
lb.configure(exportselection=False)
```

Comment: This should be the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

And if you happen to be using the python megawidgets module version of the listbox, (Pmw.ScrolledListBox(...)), doing yearsLB.component('listbox').configure(exportselection=False) worked for me.