# How to keep 2 Tkinter (python) Listboxes with multiple selections up to date?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I created a dialog using Tkinter in python. I have 2 Listbox wigets that are setup for Multiple selections. I have setup events for each listbox and use curselection to get the list of currently selected items in the list. However, when I click in the second list box, the items in the first list box are no longer highlighted. Below are some code snippets:

Creation of first list box:

```
    casebox = Listbox(self.window, listvariable=casevalues, selectmode=MULTIPLE, width=10, height=10)
    casebox.grid(column=1, row=self.dlgRow, columnspan=1, rowspan=2)
    casebox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', oncaseselect)
```

Second list box is similar:

```
    plotbox = Listbox(self.window, listvariable=plotvalues, selectmode=MULTIPLE, width=30, height=10)
    plotbox.grid(column=2, row=self.dlgRow, columnspan=2, rowspan=2)
    plotbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onplotselect)
```

The list boxes display correctly and I can preselect items:

```
  casebox.select_set(1)
  casebox.select_set(3)
```

When I try to also preselect items in the second listbox, they are selected , but the first box shows nothing selected:

```
 plotbox.select_set(1)
 plotbox.select_set(3)
```

The event handlers are:

```
 def oncaseselect(evt):
     w = evt.widget
    #self.selectedCaseList = [w.get(i) for i in w.curselection()]
    self.selectedCaseList=[]
    for i in w.curselection():
        self.selectedCaseList.append(i) 
    refreshPlotList()
    refreshCaseList()

def onplotselect(evt):
   w = evt.widget
   # self.selectedPlotList = [w.get(i) for i in w.curselection()]
   self.selectedPlotList=[]
   for i in w.curselection():
      self.selectedPlotList.append(i)        
   refreshCaseList()
   refreshPlotList()
```

I added refresh methods in an attempt to keep the selections updated:

```
def refreshCaseList():
   for item in self.selectedCaseList:
      casebox.select_set(item)

def refreshPlotList():
   for item in self.selectedPlotList:
      plotbox.select_set(pitem)
```

Without the refresh method, as soon as I click in plotbox, all the selections in case box get unselected. With the refresh methods, the same thing happens.

It seems like I can only get selected items to show in one of the listboxes - the one being clicked

Any help is appreciated.

bobls

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048609/how-to-keep-selections-highlighted-in-a-tkinter-listbox) may help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep selections highlighted in a tkinter Listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048609/how-to-keep-selections-highlighted-in-a-tkinter-listbox)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `exportselection=0` option in the Tkinter Listbox