# python tkinter listbox binding: why this function is called two times?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two `tkinter.Listbox`es. The idea is to show one of the `Listbox`es, and when an item is selected, the other `Listbox` is shown. To do that I use `grid_forget`. This is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

listbox1 = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox1.grid(row=0, column=0)

listbox1.insert(tk.END, "Item 1.1")
listbox1.insert(tk.END, "Item 1.2")

def change_listbox(event):
    
    print(listbox1.curselection())
    listbox1.grid_forget()
    listbox2.grid(row=0, column=0)

listbox1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", change_listbox)

listbox2 = tk.Listbox(root)

listbox2.insert(tk.END, "Item 2.1")
listbox2.insert(tk.END, "Item 2.2")

root.mainloop()
```

When I select an item from `listbox1`, the `listbox2` is show, but when I select an item of the `listbox2`, `change_listbox` is called again (only one time). You can check this by the `print` I added.

However, if I change `grid_forget` by `destroy` the issue is solved, but I don't want to destroy `listbox1`.

Comment: I'd imagine the item in the now-hidden listbox 1 gets deselected when you select an item in listbox 2.

Comment: It might be easier to use a single listbox and change the items therein instead of juggling two listboxes, anyway.

Comment: @AKX using only one listbox was the first thing I considered. But in the full code, `listbox1` has a fixed content and `listbox2` content depends on the selection of `listbox2`. So I decided to replace `listbox1` by ``listbox2` when an item is selected.

Comment: Add `exportselection=0` to both listboxes.

Comment: @acw1668 it works! Write an answer (and explain why) and I will choose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because when item in `listbox2` is selected, the selected item in `listbox1` will be deselected due to `exportselection` option is set to `True` by default.  So it will trigger the bound event `<<ListboxSelect>>` on `listbox1`. Just set `exportselection=False` (or 0) in both listboxes will fix it.

Comment: This might be useful too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048609/how-to-keep-selections-highlighted-in-a-tkinter-listbox

Answer (score 1):

Since the calls are

```
(0,)
```

(or `(1,)`) when initially selecting the item from the listbox, followed by

```
()
```

(i.e. "nothing selected") it looks like the second invocation occurs when the item gets unselected from list 1 (since you're selecting an item from list 2).

You can verify this by laying out both listboxes side by side (so remove the `forget` stuff):

```
listbox1.grid(row=0, column=0)
listbox2.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

When you select an item in the second listbox, the selection in the first listbox is unselected.

If you don't care about that unselection, well... don't:

```
def change_listbox(event):
    sel = listbox1.curselection()
    if not sel:  # Nothing selected, whatever
        return
    print("Selected:", sel)
    # show list 2 or something...
```

Comment: You are right... so it is a `tkinter` behaviour. So the proporsals are: use one listbox or destroy it.

Comment: Or just ignore the deselection event (i.e. when `curselection()` is falsy).

Comment: Other option I considered is to remove the binding: `def change_listbox(event): listbox1.unbind("<ListboxSelect>"); print(listbox1.curselection())`. But the issue is not solved.

Comment: Please see my edit – if you don't care about the deselection, just don't :)