# _tkinter.TclError: bad listbox index "" unwelcome <Listboxselect> event by selecting text in a Entry Widget

Tags: python, tkinter, events, listbox

I have a Listbox and a Entry Widget. If i have selected an item in the Listbox per  Bind and now click in the Entry Widget and try to invert a text input, there comes a ListboxSelect Event. How can i avoid this ?

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ANCHOR, ttk
    from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Listbox plus Entry')
    my_list = ['Adam', 'Bert', 'Claudia', 'Eva', 'Goldi']
    var = tk.Variable(value=my_list)

    my_Listbox = tk.Listbox(
        root,
        listvariable=var,
        height=6,
        selectmode=tk.SINGLE
    )

    my_Listbox.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    my_word = tk.StringVar()
    def item_selected(event):
        # selected_indice = my_Listbox.curselection()
        # selected_word = my_Listbox.get(selected_indice)
        selected_word = my_Listbox.get(ANCHOR)
        msg = f'You selected: {selected_word}'
        showinfo(title= "Listbox - Info", message=msg)
        # my_Listbox.select_clear(0, tk.END)

    my_Listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", item_selected)
    my_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=my_word).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `exportselection=0` in `tk.Listbox(...)` to disable the clear of selection when there is other selection in other widget:

```py
my_Listbox = tk.Listbox(
    root,
    listvariable=var,
    height=6,
    selectmode=tk.SINGLE,
    exportselection=0
)
```

Comment: Both codes are same results.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Do you understand what OP problem is?

Comment: See also :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048609/how-to-keep-selections-highlighted-in-a-tkinter-listbox)