# Generating 2 click-select ListBoxes in a GUI. One isn't working. Getting an error

Tags: tkinter, listbox, cursor, z-index

I have two listBoxes, each referencing a separate text file. When I click in the classList box it works (cursor selection populates to a text box).

If I click in the speciesList box first, nothing happens at all (no populating to text box, no error). If I click the classList first, then click the speciesList I get an error:

> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1948, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\owner\OneDrive\Desktop\CS113\Final\CharBuilder GUI.py", line 6, in classList
> line= lst1.get(lst1.curselection())
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 3253, in get
> return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get', first)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> _tkinter.TclError: bad listbox index "": must be active, anchor, end, @x,y, or a number
> Exception in Tkinter callback

```
def speciesList(lineList2):
    line2= lst2.get(lst2.curselection()) 
    lineList2= line2.split(',')
    txt15.delete(1.0, tk.END) 
    txt15.insert(tk.END, lineList2[0])
    return lineList2[0]

def classList(lineList):
    line= lst1.get(lst1.curselection()) 
    lineList= line.split(',')
    txt8.delete(1.0, tk.END) 
    txt8.insert(tk.END, lineList[0])
    return lineList[0]

infile = open("datafiles/specieslist.txt", 'r') 
for line2 in infile:
    ##line= line.split(',')
    lst2.insert(tk.END, line2) 
infile.close() 

lst1=tk.Listbox(height=6, width=25) 
lst1.grid(column=6, row=1, rowspan=5) 
lst1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", classList) 

infile = open("datafiles/classlist.txt", 'r') 
for line in infile:
    ##line= line.split(',')
    lst1.insert(tk.END, line) 
infile.close()
```

The expectation is I click each list and populate the selected item to its corresponding text box.

Really mystified by what the issue is. I copy/pasted the code from the working listBox and renamed the variables (as far as I can tell I got them all), and changed the file references appropriately.

Comment: line= lst1.get(lst1.curselection()[0])

Comment: adding [0] to classList didn't do anything.
adding [0] to speciesList now generates another error: "IndexError: tuple index out of range"

Comment: Corrected a dumb error where lst2.bind didn't have speciesList specified. So, now the click on that box registers, BUT whenever I click from one box to the other I get an error message: "_tkinter.TclError: bad listbox index "": must be active, anchor, end, @x,y, or a number"
Order of clicks doesn't matter (click class then species, or species then class), and each time I click back and forth it generates the error again.

Comment: Just noticed that if I click in either box, then double-click in any other field (the text boxes, for instance), I get the same error. I'm a total Python novice, but it looks to me like it's cursor select more than 1 object is the issue, but I don't know how to address that at all.

Comment: You had something like this `selectmode=MULTIPLE`

Comment: I'm not clear on how to utilize that here. From a little search it appears selectmode=MULTIPLE is for making multiple selections in a single textbox. Does that whole true for more than one textbox? Also, since I'm using the selections from each box separately, I'm not sure how to implement that selection.

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre] as there is no code on how `lst2` is created.

Comment: You're assuming that `lst1.curselection()` returns an integer. It might not if nothing is selected. Your code needs to be prepared for that. You might also want to check out this question: [How to keep selections highlighted in a tkinter Listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048609/how-to-keep-selections-highlighted-in-a-tkinter-listbox/10050053#10050053)